# Loading text before data is loaded AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone have a clue how to create a loading text before angular loads data in to a list?

I have this code for getting info from different subwebs (in sharepoint). But before (or while) the list is loaded I want to display a text "Loading...":

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {

    var webs = this._webs.getEnumerator();

    while (webs.moveNext()) {
        var subWeb = webs.get_current();

            $scope.sites.push({
                title: webs.get_title(),
            });
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    }
}),
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Site
            </th>
            <th>
                Created
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="site in sites">
        <tr>
            <td>
              {{site.title}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{site.created | date:dateFormat}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tbody ng-if="sites.length == 0">
<tr>
   <td>
      <img src="loading.gif">
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-repeat="site in sites" ng-if="sites.length > 0">
    <tr>
        <td>
          {{site.title}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{site.created | date:dateFormat}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This produce 2 watchers but it will help.

Comment: This was a easy solution that solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well.. This doesn't work if there's no site. Then it just stays in "loading" mode. If there's no site I want to display a text "There's no site available".

Comment: in controller make $scope.switch = 1 (and ng-if="switch === 1" with loading).
in executeQueryAsync on end make 
if($scope.sites.lengt > 0) {$scope.switch = 3} (and ng-if="switch === 3" with table list)
if($scope.sites.lengt === 0) {$scope.switch = 2} (and ng-if="switch === 2" with no results message)

Comment: Got it working, had to add $scope.apply inside the if-statements. Thanks Michał.

Answer (score 0):

some links of loading indicator :  [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner)

also [BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) detailing on how the spinner works with angularjs

and in case you want to implement it yourself, below code will get you started...

```
app.directive("spinner", function(){
return: {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {enable:"="},
template: <div class="spinner" ng-show="enable"><img src="content/spinner.gif"></div>
}
});
```

warning : i havent tested the code but directive wont be more complex than this...